# How many olympic gold medal ties have there been?

Tags: trivia, history, olympics

Simone Manuel [tied for the gold](http://www.teamusa.org/News/2016/August/11/Simone-Manuel-Wins-100-Free-Is-First-African-American-Female-Swimmer-To-Win-Individual-Medal) with Penny Oleksiak in the 100m freestyle during the 2016 Summer Olympics. I have never seen this before, and was curious how often it happens. I tried to find information, and in fact the first article I linked to says that there was a tie in this same event in 1984, but I can't find a list of other events where this has happened, within swimming and beyond.

All I found were articles like about a downhill skiing gold medal tie between Tina Maze and Dominique Gisin in 2014, and [one that addresses this incident](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/what-happens-when-theres-tie-olympics-180949754/?no-ist) and lists the ties from only the Winter Olympics.

Does anyone know how many gold medal ties there have been in Olympic history, in both the summer and winter games?

Comment: There was a 3-way tie for silver for the Mens 100m Butterfly.  PHELPS (USA), LE CLOS (S. Africa), CSEH (Hungary)  https://www.rio2016.com/en/swimming-mens-100m-butterfly-final

Answer (score 2):

Summer Olympic Games: 27 gold medal ties. (The source below says 26 times as of 2014...so the Manuel/Oleksiak tie would be 27 -- looking for a better source).

Winter Olympic Games: [8 gold medal ties](http://olympstats.com/2014/02/12/ties-for-medals-at-the-winter-olympics/).